# Загрузить файл в input[file] по ссылке на кариинку

Tags: javascript, input

Как мне, зная ссылку на файл, (например, http://host/filepath/filename.png) загрузить его в `input[file]` для отправки на сервер?

Comment: в таком случае правильно будет передать ссылку на файл в виде текста(<input type="text">) а на бэке загрузить уже средствами серверной части. Для php например `$file = file_get_contents($_POST['file_link']);`

Comment: @Arendach я бы так и сделал, если бы не тот факт, что отправить мне нужно в админку django, следовательно что бы изменить сохранение файла, нужно расширять класс django, что то же несёт за собой изрядную порцию геморроя

Answer (score 3):

Благодаря ответам @ТрипольскийПётр и ещё некоторым ресурсам я смог решить появившуюся проблему. Решение выглядит следующим образом:
`

```
//Функция для получения объекта Blob

    async function fetchImage(url){
        const data = await fetch(url);
        console.log(data);
        const buffer = await data.arrayBuffer();
        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/png"});
        return blob;
    }
```

`С помощь. этой функции я получаю файл по ссылке на него.`

```
//Добавление файла в input['file']
let url = 'http://host/filepath/filename.png'
let nameFile ='file.png';
let inputForm = document.getElementById('id');
const blob = await fetchImage(url);
const file = new File([blob],nameFile)
const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
dT.items.add(file);
inputForm.files = dT.files;
```

`

Таким образом я отправляю файл в форме, получая его с другого ресурса.

Comment: У меня была задача загрузить изображение, со своего же сервера в input type file. Тоже воспользовался вашим подходом, чтобы не трогать бэк. 

Конечно удивился, что изображение, которое есть у тебя же на странице нельзя просто добавить в input, а надо заново качать и через буфер обмена вставлять.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно. Сохраните файл как index.html **на локальный жесткий** диск и откройте как файл **без веб сервера**, чтобы не получить ошибку [CORS Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

```
<body>
    <script>
        (async function() {
            const fetchImage = async (url) => {
                const data = await fetch(url);
                const buffer = await data.arrayBuffer();
                const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/png"});
                return blob;
            }
            const sendImage = (blob, url = "http://foo.com/submitform.php",  name = "image.png") => {
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                const file = new File([blob], name)
                const data = new FormData();
                request.open("POST", url);
                data.append("image", file, name);
                request.send(data);
            }
            const showImage = (blob) => {
                const image = document.createElement("img");
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                document.body.appendChild(image);  
            }
            const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/JavaScript-logo.png";
            const blob = await fetchImage(url);
            showImage(blob);
            // sendImage(blob);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Если же вам нужно подобрать несколько файлов, можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
class MultiplePicker {
    constructor() {
        this._input = document.createElement("input");
        this._input.setAttribute("type", "file");
        this._input.setAttribute("multiple", '');
        this._input.style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(this._input);
    }
    pick() {
        this._input.click();
    }
    get files() {
        return this._input.files;
    }
}

...

const picker = new MultiplePicker();
picker.pick();
picker.files // FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, length: 3}
```

Comment: Решение вроде выглядит неплохо, но появилась проблема. При создании экземпляра File выдаёт ошибку  `TypeError: Argument 1 of File.constructor can't be converted to a sequence.`

Comment: @НикельВиктор поправил код, вроде бы, в конструктор следует подавать массив из blob, пробуйте...

Comment: да, это я уже поправил, не успел написать (за подобные конструкции я прям всем сердцем ненавижу js). Но наткнулся на новую проблема. Дело в том, что мне очень не хочеться править бекенд (в данном случаи это админка django) и мне нужно отдать форму в которой есть input[file], в котором должен быть файл. Но я не могу добавить полученный файл в FileList

Comment: @НикельВиктор Проще всего будет создать невидимый элемент input. Пометьте вопрос как правильный, если не трудно. Обновленный код см в ответе